# Drop rows pandas based on combination of matched column values with other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Set-up**

I have 2 pandas dfs (df1 and df2) which contain some overlapping rows and some non-overlapping rows.

Both dfs have the columns `order_id` and `shop`.

Now, if a row in df1 matches any row in df2 on the combination of `order_id` and `shop`, then this row should be dropped from df1. If this row doesn't match any row in df2 on `order_id` and `shop`, it should be kept.

---

**Example**

`df2` is such that,

```
    order_id    shop
0     12345     'NL'
1     45678     'FR'
2     12345     'DE'
3     34567     'NL'
```

Now if `df1` such that,

```
    order_id    shop
0     12345     'NL'
1     45678     'FR'
```

then df1 should return empty.

---

But if `df1` such that,

```
        order_id    shop
0       12345       'NL'
1       99999       'FR'
2       12345       'UK'
```

then `df1` should return,

```
        order_id    shop
0       99999       'FR'
1       12345       'UK'
```

---

**Code**

I created a monstrous line which then didn't really work...

So far, I have,

```
result_df = df1[(~df1['order_id'].astype(str).isin(df2['order_id'].astype(str)))]
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are not same types of columns, so first convert it to `string` and then `merge` with `indicator=True`:

```
df3 = (df1.astype(str).merge(df2.astype(str), how='left', indicator=True)
          .query('_merge == "left_only"')[df1.columns])
print (df3)
   order_id  shop
2     99999  'FR'
3     12345  'UK'
```

Also is possible check if same dtypes before solution:

```
print (df1.dtypes)
print (df2.dtypes))
```

And convert only column(s) which is different `dtype`:

```
df2['order_id'] = df2['order_id'].astype(str)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it returns rows which are already in `df1`.

Comment: @LucSpan - Not sure, what is problem, for me it working nice. Not swapped `df1` with `df2`, so need `df3 = (df2.astype(str).merge(df1.astype(str), how='left', indicator=True)
          .query('_merge == "left_only"')[df1.columns])` ?

Comment: Ya I know. I tried yours on the example and it worked fine. Maybe it has to do with the data in the actual dfs.

Comment: @LucSpan - hm, it seems some data related problem like trailing whitespaces or matching floats or similar. Then best is export values to list by `df3.to_dict('list')` and check if some differencies.

Comment: somehow it's not working for me. instead of bringing up only non matched rows this gives every row in left dataframe.

Comment: @user12345 - Are dtypes same?

Comment: yea same dtypes for both